# Powershell If condition not working

Tags: windows, powershell, if-statement

I need to search inside multiple OU in my AD and check the password never expires status.
I have first user with passwordneverexpires = "True" in OU test1.
Another user with passwordneverexpires = "False" in OU test2
Below is my code:

```
$searchRoot = @("mydomain.com/TEst/test1")
$searchRoot += @("mydomain.com/TEst/test2")

remove-variable inactiveUsers

Foreach ($ou in $searchRoot) {
$inactiveUsers += @(Get-QADUser -SearchRoot $ou -Enabled | Select-Object Name,SamAccountName,passwordneverexpires | Sort-Object Name)
}

if ($inactiveUsers -ne $null){
foreach($user in $inactiveUsers){
If ($user.passwordneverexpires -eq "False") {write-host $user.passwordneverexpires}
}
}
```

I want the script to do nothing for first user (because it passwordneverexpires = "True",
and return something for second user (passwordneverexpires = "False".
However with the script above I'm always getting "True" as result.
not sure what's wrong with my script. I'm running it on Win 2003 PS 2.0. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are Boolean values.

Try

```
If ($user.passwordneverexpires -eq $false)
```

or

```
If ($user.passwordneverexpires.tostring() -eq "False")
```